# sql server dynamic calculated field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I need a calculated field based on each record in sql server 2000. 
for example there is  a table like this:

```
col1 col2 calcfield
-------------------
1     2   col1+col2
3     5   col1*col2
```

I need a query to calculate the last field per record eg:

```
1     2     3
3     5     15
```

Actually This is a system that calculates a number for some persons.There are some parameters stored in fields of a table and there is another field that stores how to calculate the number from those parameters(that is the formula). for each person there are different parameters and a different formula. I want to design a query that can extract parameters and the calculated column directly from the table

Is there any way to do this and if there is what is the best and fastest way....

best regards

Comment: how do you distinguish between the rows that are added and those that are multiplied?

Comment: If there are a *fixed*, *enumerable* set of functions that each row might want applied, **and** the result of each calculation is the same datatype, it should be doable. So how many different functions are we dealing with?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but my main  problem is that there is no fixed formula and it is definable. The end user will define the calculated field in a table and this table is joined to another one

Answer (score 2):

You just do the math and alias it.  Por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  field2,
  field1 + field2 AS 'CalcField'
FROM table
```

If you need to do different calculations depending on the record, use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  field2,
  CASE 
    WHEN (some condition) THEN field1 + field2 
    WHEN (some other condition) THEN field1 * field2
    ELSE (some default value or calculation)
    END AS 'CalcField'
FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the main problem is, the calculated field  is defined by the end user and it can hold different calculation formulas...

Comment: Ssnkh, you should update your op to better convey what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a system that calculates a number for some persons.There are some parameters stored in fields of a table and there is another field that stores how to calculate the number from those parameters(that is the formula). for each person there are different parameters and different formula. I want to design a query that can extract parameters and the calculated column directly from the table.

Comment: I meant to update the post at the top of the page so that other people see it.